# New Request in RxJs interval

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an interval in my application that gets information from API every 2 minutes. This interval do 3 call at the same time, gets some list and do some stuff with it.

In this list, there are some items. I want to delete one item and then re-call the list (interval) to get the new list updated and show it (without wait the interval time, basically, refresh the call). But I don't know how. I tried to create a subject and with a `.next ('')`, call the interval again (with consequent errors, ofc). I think I'm missing something related to the operation of `switchMap` and polling .

```
    const created$ = this.collections.getMyCollections('created'); // returns Observable<Collection[]>
    const asigns$ = this.collections.getMyCollections('asigns');
    const groups$ = this.collections.getMyCollections('groups');

    /** Interval*/
    let pollInterval = 120000;
    let timer$ = timer(0, pollInterval);


    /** subscriptions */
    this.pollingSubscription  = timer$.pipe(switchMap(() => forkJoin(creates$, asigns$, groups$))).subscribe(([CREATED, ASIGNS, GROUPS]) => {
        /** Some stuff here*/
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could switch from `forkJoin` to a combineLatest of a BehaviorSubject:

```
const created$ = this.collections.getMyCollections("created"); // returns Observable<Collection[]>
const asigns$ = this.collections.getMyCollections("asigns");
const groups$ = this.collections.getMyCollections("groups");

const refresh$ = new BehaviorSubject<"created" | "asigns" | "groups" | "init">(
  "init"
);

/** Interval*/
let pollInterval = 120000;
let timer$ = timer(0, pollInterval);

/** subscriptions */
this.pollingSubscription = timer$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() =>
      combineLatest(
        refresh$.pipe(
          filter(refreshId => refreshId === 'created' || refreshId === 'init'),
          switchMap(() => created$)
        ),
        refresh$.pipe(
          filter(refreshId => refreshId === 'asigns' || refreshId === 'init'),
          switchMap(() => asigns$)
        ),
        refresh$.pipe(
          filter(refreshId => refreshId === 'groups' || refreshId === 'init'),
          switchMap(() => groups$)
        )
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(([CREATED, ASIGNS, GROUPS]) => {
    /** Some stuff here*/
  });
```

The `BehaviorSubject` would emit `'init'` upon subscription which would trigger the 3 observables in the `combineLatest`.
As soon as you want to refresh one of the collections you can call:

```
this.refresh$.next('created');
// OR
this.refresh$.next('asigns');
// OR
this.refresh$.next('groups');
```

I didn't test this code, it's the general idea. I think you may have to rewrite the timer part a little bit to avoid having multiple subscribers over time.

Comment: It works like a charm! In addition, being able to isolate each request individually, it works much better and allows me to scale the functionality much better! Very gratefully!

Comment: Cool! :) just check when the timer runs if it doesn't create a second subscription. Not sure it would, but as I didn't test I don't have a clear mind on this.
(Do not forget to accept the answer if you think it's the one which solves your problem)

Comment: Just one thing. If I delete a collection, I'm watching that If I refresh the 'created', the next request  in the interval are always the created one, not created+asigns+groups

Comment: What do you mean by "delete" ?

Comment: The purpose of this is, given one of the 3 list that I retrieve from API, being able to delete an item from one of those list and update the list (refresh button). if I delete an item from the created list, the subsequent calls will be 'created' instead of 'init'.

Answer (score 0):

My preference for forkJoin is the following pattern, which might help you if there's stuff you want to do after one of the forkJoin methods has emitted its value.

Each observable takes care of its own after effects in its own pipe rather than delegating to the subscribe body.

```
forkJoin([
  observable1.pipe(
    tap(res1 => this.res1 = res1)
  ),
  observable2.pipe(
    tap(res2 => this.res2 = res2),
    // run additional observable this could be conditional if you need it to be
    switchMap(() => observable2a.run()),
    tap(res2a => this.res2a = res2a)
  ),
  observable3.pipe(
    tap(res3 => this.res = res3)
  )
]).subscribe(() => {
  // clean subscribe body
  // do whatever you need to do now all observables have run  
});
```

The benefit of this is that it keeps your observable dependencies together, and prevents the subscribe body becoming a big mess.

It's a little unclear where the delete might take place in your code, but I think this pattern might help you.